# @Async and @Transactional: not working

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Please see code.

1. When I called the method @Async loadMarkUpPCT(), data is NOT committed into the table. It behaves as if it's non-tractional.
2. When I removed @Async from loadMarkUpPCT (Class 1), i.e. non-async, then data is committed and OK as expected: transactional)

I was expecting to have the same result with @Async and @Transactional but it's NOT. Please explain or what did I do wrong?

**Edited:** I just edited to post the code + log

Flow-wise:
AppDataLoaderController calls AppDataLoaderService 
calls DataMigrationService calls JpaDataMigrationDao

```
package concepts.web.rest.resource.spring.impl;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appdataloader")
public class AppDataLoaderController {

    @RequestMapping("/loadMarkupPct")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)    
    public void loadMarkUpPCT() {
        try {
            this.appDataLoaderService.loadMarkUpPCT();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



package concepts.service.impl;  

@Service("appDataLoaderService")
public class AppDataLoaderServiceImpl implements AppDataLoaderService {

    @Async
    @Override       
    public void loadMarkUpPCT() throws ServiceException {
        logger.debug("@Async loadMarkUpPCT");       
        dataMigrationService.loadMarkUpPCT();
    }   


package concepts.service.impl;

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class DataMigrationServiceImpl implements DataMigrationService {

    @Override
    public void loadMarkUpPCT() throws ServiceException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Assert.notNull(markUpPCTDataLoader);
        List<MarkUpPCT> markUpPCTs=markUpPCTDataLoader.getMarkupCoef();
        for (MarkUpPCT markUpPCT: markUpPCTs)
            dataMigrationDao.storeMarkUpPCT(markUpPCT);
    }


package concepts.persistence.impl.jpa;

@Repository
public class JpaDataMigrationDao extends DataMigrationDaoAdapter{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void storeMarkUpPCT(MarkUpPCT markUpPCT) {
        entityManager.persist(markUpPCT);

    }
```

Some logs

```
14 Nov 2013 18:47:05,531 36813 [http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter  - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
14 Nov 2013 18:47:05,578 36860 [http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc' processing POST request for [/POCQI/appdataloader/loadMarkupPct]
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /appdataloader/loadMarkupPct
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Returning handler method [public void concepts.web.rest.resource.spring.impl.AppDataLoaderController.loadMarkUpPCT()]
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG DataMigrationServiceImpl  - @Async loadMarkUpPCT
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG DispatcherServlet  - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG MarkUpPCTDataLoader  - {80=1.6, 90=1.8, 100=2.0, 105=2.05, 110=2.1, 115=2.15, 117=2.17, 120=2.2, 125=2.25, 150=2.5}
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter  - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
[http-bio-18080-exec-3] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Opening JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG EntityManagerFactoryUtils  - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Comment: Please post your config for both `@Async` and `@Transactinal`.

Comment: I used Spring 3.2

applicationContext-service.xml
 <task:annotation-driven />
 
applicationContext-jpa.xml 
     <tx:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Please post both of those files and the packages in which your classes appear in.

Comment: Flow:
AppDataLoaderController calls AppDataLoaderService 
calls DataMigrationService calls JpaDataMigrationDao

Comment: Sotirios, I just posted the code + log.

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to also annotate the `loadMarkUpPCT()` method with `@Transactional` and tell us if that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same issue. Turns out I forgot to add the @EnableAsync annotation.